# Flutter - How to create responsive CircleAvatar widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a responsibility for the `CircleAvatar` widget, but I am not sure how.
Here is my code:

```
body: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(...),
                      if (_isAvatar) 
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            maxRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.width +
                                78, // Here is a problem, how to calc width to fit on any device?
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                _pageContent['acf']['doctor']['avatar']),
                          ),
                        ),
                      Container(...),
                    ],
                  )),
                ])));
```

I want to make the widget responsive and fittable on any device or resolutio.
I am Flutter's newbie, please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use radius, not maxRadius. Here's the code:

```
CircleAvatar(
   radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3, //change 0.3 to any value you want
   backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
      _pageContent['acf']['doctor']['avatar']),
   ),
),
```

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 67 pixels on the right.

Comment: In the example I provided, I set the Circle Avatar to take 30% of the width. If your Row contains more than 3 children, you'll probably get a RenderFlex. Try to change the radius value based on the the number of children in you row. For example, if you have 10 children in the row, your Circle Avatar radius should not be more than MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1 (which is 10% of width for each). 
Note that the percentage you choose should take into consideration the padding and margin.